# How to set the view source multiple html frames in single viewsource

Tags: javascript, html, frame, view-source

I have three frames in single frameset html page. when i saw the view source of the page look like below

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>A simple frameset document</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
<FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%">
<FRAMESET rows="100, 200">
  <FRAME src="contents_of_frame1.html">
   <FRAME src="contents_of_frame2.html">
</FRAMESET>
<FRAME src="contents_of_frame3.html">

  </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

but my expectation is i want to display the whole frame source in single page using javascript.
thanks

Comment: Whoa, sorry, i have to say. `The 90's called, they want their frames back` :)

Comment: @Valamas-AUS i know but, we need

Comment: I didn't understand your question... You want to convert your frameset to a single page, and load/reload content parts dynamically with javascript ?

Comment: @Akaryatrh I have set of frames in index.html page while view source that page I get the result like above code, but i need view source with contents_of_frame1.html, contents_of_frame2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this bookmarklet?

Note:

1. I use XMP, it is deprecated but should work on most browsers
2. it will attempt to open a new window so allow it
3. it assumes the frame contents have `<HTML>` tags
4. paste the script into a bookmark URL and execute the bookmark on the page
5. Tested in Chrome on Windows

```
javascript:(function() { 
  var htmlContent=[]; 
  for (var i=0;i<window.frames.length;i++) {
    var fr = window.frames[i], doc=fr.contentDocument || fr.document;
    htmlContent.push(doc.getElementsByTagName("HTML")[0].innerHTML);
  }
  var w=window.open('');
  for (var i=0;i<htmlContent.length;i++) {
    w.document.write('Frame '+i+':<hr/><xm'+'p>'+htmlContent[i]+'</xmp><hr/>')
  }
  w.document.close();
})()
```

Testing with this html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Demo by mplungjan</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var contents_of_frame1 = '<html><head><title>Frame1</title><script>alert("frame 1")<\/script></head><body>Frame1</body></html>';
var contents_of_frame2 = '<html><head><title>Frame2</title><script>alert("frame 2")<\/script></head><body>Frame 2</body></html>';
var contents_of_frame3 = '<html><head><title>Frame3</title><script>alert("frame 3")<\/script></head><body>Frame 3</body></html>';
</script>
</head>
  <FRAMESET cols="20%, 80%">
    <FRAMESET rows="100, 200">
      <FRAME src="javascript:top.contents_of_frame1" />
      <FRAME src="javascript:top.contents_of_frame2" />
    </FRAMESET>
  <FRAME src="javascript:top.contents_of_frame3" />
</FRAMESET>
</html>
```

I get this output

Frame 0:

---

`<head><title>Frame1</title><script>alert("frame 1")</script></head><body>Frame1</body>`

Frame 1:

---

`<head><title>Frame2</title><script>alert("frame 2")</script></head><body>Frame 2</body>`

Frame 2:

---

`<head><title>Frame3</title><script>alert("frame 3")</script></head><body>Frame 3</body>`

Comment: we have insert your javascript in my index page and tested but it display like:output -> Frame 0:
<head></head><body></body>
Frame 1:
<head></head><body></body>
Frame 2:
<head></head><body></body> but element is not captured.

Comment: The way I wrote it, it is a bookmarklet. It does not run in a page but from the bookmark bar